# Question about quantum control gates where the two qubits are different bases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, superposition

[image]

I understand the first (top) qubit. If I define |-> in terms of the z-basis,

|-> = (1/sqrt(2))(|0> - |1>)

And analyzing each component passing through at a time, I see that (1/sqrt(2))|0> is transformed to -(1/sqrt(2))|1>, and (1/sqrt(2))|1> is transformed to -(1/sqrt(2))|0>.

This result, combined with doing the matrix algebra on |->[X][Z] = -(1/sqrt(2))[-1; -1] shows that the output on qubit 1 is -|+>.

As for the bottom qubit, I'm not as clear as how to express it as an output state, nor do I fully understand how to solve for it using matrix algebra. Instead, I recognize when the input to qubit 1 is a |1>, neither of the lower operators are activated, and the output state is |0>, like the input state.

However, when qubit 1's input state is |0>, both lower operators are activated, and I find |0>[H][X] = |->.

So in the case where the first qubit is a superposition of |1> and |0>, is the second qubit a superposition of |-> and |0>? If the probability of |1> or |0> for input 1 are both 0.5, would the second output state be (1/sqrt(2))(|-> + |0>)?

Answer (score 2):

For double Qubit gates one has to evolve the two qubits simultaneously, since they are likely in an entangled state. Here are the step by step state transformations:

1. X gate on qubit one turns it into $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(|1\rangle - |0\rangle)$. Combining with second quite, the overall state is $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(|1\rangle|0\rangle - |0\rangle|0\rangle)$.
2. Control-H gate turns $|1\rangle|0\rangle$ into $|1\rangle|+\rangle$ and does nothing on $|0\rangle|0\rangle$. So the state becomes $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(|1\rangle|+\rangle - |0\rangle|0\rangle)$.
3. Z-gate on first qubit changes the sign of $|1\rangle|+\rangle$ to negative, and leaves the second part of the state unchanged. The state now is $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(-|1\rangle|+\rangle - |0\rangle|0\rangle)$.
4. Control-Z gate only change the sign of state $|1\rangle|1\rangle$. As a result the final state is $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(-|1\rangle|-\rangle - |0\rangle|0\rangle)$.

This is an entangled state which cannot be reduced as a product of the state of first qubit and the state of second qubit.